# I can't run socket server

Tags: sockets, server

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket()
print("Server created")

s.bind(("localhost", 1111))

s.listen(5)
print("weiting for connection...")

while True:
    c, adr = s.accept()
    print(adr + " is connecter")
    
    c.send("You connected to server")
    
    c.close()
```

That was my code in python3

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 6, in <module>
    s.bind (("localhost", 1111))
OSError: [WinError 10048] Each socket address (protocol / network address / port) can normally only be used once
```

This is error that pops up when I am trying to run my socket server! Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: did you perhaps leave a previous instance of the server bound and using up that port? check your OS's process monitor and terminate any instances of your program before trying again.

Comment: Your sample code doesn't reproduce the problem.  Paste the real code not a (mis)re-typed attempt.  Make a [mcve] and steps necessary to reproduce.  Test it, then cut-n-paste it.